# How to loop through arraylist to see if any objects have the same value

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of cars, I want to loop through this array list and see if two cars are in the exact same position, so I can see if they have collided. I wrote the following but all I get is 'no collision' even when they have collided. I put it in two methods. My assumption is that since both loops are looping from the same point are they just constantly checking the same car together or something like that? So the if (i != collided) is getting triggered everytime? How do i stop this if so?

```
public void carCollision(Car collided) {

    for (Car i: cars) {
        if(i != collided && i.getLane() == collided.getLane() && 
            i.getPosition() == collided.getPosition()) {
            System.out.println("collision");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no collisions");
        }
    }
}

public void check() {
    for (Car a: cars) {
        carCollision(a);
    }
}
```

Car class -

```
/** State of a car on the road */
public class Car {

/** Position of this car on the road (i.e. how far down the road it is) in pixels */
private double position;
/** Current speed in pixels per second */
private double speed;
/** Lane that this car is on */
private int lane;
/** Colour of this car's display */
private Color color;

public Car(double position, double speed, int lane, Color color) {
    this.position = position;
    this.speed = speed;
    this.lane = lane;
    this.color = color;
}

/** @return a new Car object with the same state as this one */
public Car clone() {
    return new Car(position, speed, lane, color);
}

/** Update this car after `elapsed' seconds have passed */
public void tick(Environment environment, double elapsed) {
    position += speed * elapsed;
}

public double getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public int getLane() {
    return lane;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}
```

This is my main class to show how I am calling the method, i use e.check(); in the addcars method -

```
public class Main extends Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

public void start(Stage stage) {

    final Environment environment = new Environment();
    final Display display = new Display(environment);
    environment.setDisplay(display);

    VBox box = new VBox();

    stage.setTitle("Traffic");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(box, 800, 600));

    HBox controls = new HBox();
    Button restart = new Button("Restart");
    controls.getChildren().addAll(restart);
    box.getChildren().add(controls);

    restart.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            environment.clear();
            display.reset();
            addCars(environment);
        });

    box.getChildren().add(display);

    addCars(environment);

    stage.show();
}

/** Add the required cars to an environment.
 *  @param e Environment to use.
 */
private static void addCars(Environment e) {
    /* Add an `interesting' set of cars */
    Random r = new Random();
    e.add(new Car(  0, 63, 2, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car( 48, 79, 0, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(144, 60, 0, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(192, 74, 0, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(240, 12, 1, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(288, 77, 0, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(336, 28, 1, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(384, 32, 2, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.add(new Car(432, 16, 1, new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), 1.0)));
    e.check();
}
};
```

Update to include my environment class, the question is quite long winded now but i feel the problem may be in how I am using the environment class?

```
public class Environment implements Cloneable {

/** All the cars that are on our road */
private ArrayList<Car> cars = new ArrayList<Car>();
/** The Display object that we are working with */
private Display display;
/** Number of lanes to have on the road */
private int lanes = 4;
private long last;

/** Set the Display object that we are working with.
 */
public void setDisplay(Display display) {
    this.display = display;

    /* Start a timer to update things */
    new AnimationTimer() {
        public void handle(long now) {
            if (last == 0) {
                last = now;
            }

            /* Update the model */
            tick((now - last) * 1e-9);

            /* Update the view */
            double furthest = 0;
            for (Car i: cars) {
                if (i.getPosition() > furthest) {
                    furthest = i.getPosition();
                }
            }
            display.setEnd((int) furthest);
            display.draw();
            last = now;
        }
    }.start();
}

/** Return a copy of this environment */
public Environment clone() {
    Environment c = new Environment();
    for (Car i: cars) {
        c.cars.add(i.clone());
    }
    return c;
}

/** Draw the current state of the environment on our display */
public void draw() {
    for (Car i: cars) {
        display.car((int) i.getPosition(), i.getLane(), i.getColor());
    }
}

/** Add a car to the environment.
 *  @param car Car to add.
 */
public void add(Car car) {
    cars.add(car);
}

public void clear() {
    cars.clear();
}

/** @return length of each car (in pixels) */
public double carLength() {
    return 40;
}

/** Update the state of the environment after some short time has passed */
private void tick(double elapsed) {
    Environment before = Environment.this.clone();
    for (Car i: cars) {
        i.tick(before, elapsed);
    }
}

/** @param behind A car.
 *  @return The next car in front of @ref behind in the same lane, or null if there is nothing in front on the same lane.
 */
public Car nextCar(Car behind) {
    Car closest = null;
    for (Car i: cars) {
        if (i != behind && i.getLane() == behind.getLane() && i.getPosition() > behind.getPosition() && (closest == null || i.getPosition() < closest.getPosition())) {
            closest = i;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}

public void carCollision(Car collided) {

    for (Car i: cars) {
        double MIN_DIS = 0.1;
        if(!(i.equals(collided)) && i.getLane() == collided.getLane() && 
            (Math.abs(i.getPosition() - collided.getPosition()) < MIN_DIS )) {
            System.out.println("collision");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no collisions");
        }
    }
}

public void check() {
    for (Car a: cars) {
        carCollision(a);
    }

}

public void speed() {
    for (Car a : cars) {
        a.setSpeed();
    }
}

/** @return Number of lanes */
public int getLanes() {
    return lanes;
}
```

}

UPDATE - not fixed yet, but i think im getting close. I have added the following code, using the 'nextCar' method -

```
public Car nextCar(Car behind) {
    Car closest = null;
    for (Car i: cars) {
        if (i != behind && i.getLane() == behind.getLane() && i.getPosition() > behind.getPosition() && (closest == null || i.getPosition() < closest.getPosition())) {
            closest = i;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}

public void collision() {
    Environment e = Environment.this.clone();
    double MIN_DIS = 0.5;
    for (Car i : cars) {
        e.nextCar(i);
        for (Car a : cars) {
            if(!(i.equals(a)) && i.getLane() == a.getLane() && 
                (Math.abs(i.getPosition() - a.getPosition()) < MIN_DIS)) {
            System.out.println("collision");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no collision");
        }

            System.out.println("closest car is" + i);
        }
    }
}
```

This manages to print out the closest car so i know its somewhat working, though it still wont detect a collision? Any idea what might be the issue? I call this using e.collision() in the addCars method in main

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. Start over on the explanation. Post a MCVE.

Comment: okay you have `Car` object to find two cars are collided you need to compare some properties of `Car` object right? what are they and can you upload `Car` class in post

Comment: I've posted the car class if this helps. What i want is to be able to detect when two cars on my road have collided.

Comment: If two cars are at same position and same lane then it mean collided @Chloe13, if that case check my answer

Comment: I answered @Chloe13 let me know if my answer helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54171096/10426557

Comment: It is almost never good idea compare `double`s for equivalence using `==`

Answer (score 0):

Do you invoke `check()` on each car in `cars`? The code you've posted doesn't show how you use `check()`.

Additionally, you wrote

> two cars are in the exact same position

but you have to be reminded that using floating point positions, this is really tricky. If two cars have the same initial position, speed and `tick` was called on them with the same `elapsed` argument, then they will have the same `position`. However, in any other situation, due to rounding errors, their positions may be apart by a tiny fraction, like `0.00000000001`.

You'd have to show us a complete example with a set of cars and how you call `check()` on them.

Comment: Thanks i realise they cant be exact now, i really just need to know when they touch it doesn't have to be the exact position. I will change my wording. I've now included my Main class in my original question, it shows how i called check() if that helps

Comment: The code is still not complete without the `Environment` class. You call `check()` on the `Environment` not on a `Car`. We can only assume that `Environment.check()` calls `check()` on each car in `cars`...

Comment: Moreover, you call `Environment.check()` only once in the `addCars` method, but the function should probably be called after each iteration of the simulation.

Comment: Still fixing this issue won't solve your problems. What you really want is not to compare whether two cars are in the position at some point in time, but whether two cars collided, that's something different.

Comment: For each car you need to store its previous position and current position (you can maintain previous position by adding `prevPosition = position` in the `tick` method. The `check` method should check for each pair of cars on the same lane whether their relative positions changed. This could look like: `if (i.getPosition() >= collided.getPosition() && i.getPrevPosition() < collided.getPrevPosition())`

Comment: I made a small mistake in my first comment, I thought that check() is part of some other class, but it seems it is actually part of `Environment` so it is irrelevant.

Comment: I tried writing this, though I'm not quite sure how to use the prevPosition. Do i put it in 'tick' in my car class? I also have a tick method in my environment class which i have added to my question. I have also added a new but similar approach that i tried. It doesn't quite work but I think it is closeish, if you could check this id be very grateful! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The position is a double value so position cannot be exactly same. So define a minimum distance value, and below that value collision is considered for example `MIN_DIS = 0.1`.

```
public void carCollision(Car collided) {

    for (Car i: cars) {
        if(!(i.equals(collided)) && i.getLane() == collided.getLane() && 
            (Math.abs(i.getPosition() - collided.getPosition()) < MIN_DIS)) {
            System.out.println("collision");
        } else {
            System.out.println("no collisions");
        }
    }
}

public void check() {
    for (Car a: cars) {
        carCollision(a);
    }
}
```

And your Car Class.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import org.omg.CORBA.Environment;

/** State of a car on the road */
public class Car {

    /**
     * Position of this car on the road (i.e. how far down the road it is) in
     * pixels
     */
    private double position;
    /** Current speed in pixels per second */
    private double speed;
    /** Lane that this car is on */
    private int lane;
    /** Colour of this car's display */
    private Color color;

    public Car(double position, double speed, int lane, Color color) {
        this.position = position;
        this.speed = speed;
        this.lane = lane;
        this.color = color;
    }

    /** @return a new Car object with the same state as this one */
    public Car clone() {
        return new Car(position, speed, lane, color);
    }

    /** Update this car after `elapsed' seconds have passed */
    public void tick(Environment environment, double elapsed) {
        position += speed * elapsed;
    }

    public double getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public int getLane() {
        return lane;
    }

    public Color getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public double getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof Car){
            Car car = (Car) obj;
            return car.getPosition() == this.position && car.getLane() == this.lane && car.getColor().equals(this.color) && car.getSpeed() == this.speed; 
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i still can't quite get it to work though. I've included my main class in my original question which shows how i call the method, in case there is an issue there

Comment: how you define add method in Environment Class?

Comment: I have included the environment class in my question now, maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

I have method not direct solve your problem, hope can help you.

First group,assume you hava a car list:

```
// init the cars
List<Car> cars = new ArrayList<>();

// first group
Map<Tuple2<Double,Integer>,List<Car>> groupResult = cars.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(new Function<Car, Tuple2<Double,Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public Tuple2<Double, Integer> apply(Car car) {
            return new Tuple2<>(car.getPosition(),car.getLane());
        }
    }));
```

Second check the number of group result:

if the size of List from group result is not 1,so there car in the same postion。