# Collision detection between two objects in java

Tags: java, for-loop, math, methods, collision-detection

I'm really struggling detecting collision between two Car objects of Car class. The code is pretty long so its hard to include it all. I've included my collision method. If you can spot any logic errors with it which I'm thinking is my issue that'd be great. If you need more context I asked an earlier similar question which includes a lot more of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54170987/how-to-loop-through-arraylist-to-see-if-any-objects-have-the-same-value), but i still dont have a solution..

What i want it to do is tell me when two cars are touching. What it's doing is nothing but printing 'no collision' even when there are collisions.

collision method (inside environment class) -

```
public boolean collision() {

    double MIN_DIS = 0.1;
    for (Car a : cars) {
        for (Car b : cars) {
            if (!(a.equals(b)) && (Math.abs(a.getPosition() - b.getPosition()) < MIN_DIS)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Calling method (inside main where i add cars) -

```
    if(e.collision() == true) {
        System.out.println("collision");
    } else {
        System.out.println("no collision");
    }
```

Equals method (i decided to use !(a == b) for now though) -

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Car){
        Car car = (Car) obj;
        return car.getPosition() == this.position && car.getLane() == this.lane && car.getColor().equals(this.color) && car.getSpeed() == this.speed; 
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: what does `getPosition` return? a double?

Comment: is a `Car` just a single point? Are you sure they are actually colliding, where are they / what is their position at the time you expect a collision? Add a lot of logging.

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning yeah it returns a double

Comment: Also, have you implemented your own `equals` in `Car`? just trying to narrow it down

Comment: I see. Does it detect a collision when you up the `MIN_DIS` to something large like 100? If so it might just be an issue of using too small of a value

Comment: @luk2302 the car moves along a lane in a road. I have 4 lanes, 9 cars, they all start at different positions and go at different speeds. The road is a straight line, all they do is go forward. I expect collision when the two cars are touching. Right now they just go straight through eachother

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning when i up the MIN_DIS to 50, it returns collision but even where there is no collision, my cars length is 40 so 40 should do it but i've tried every number in between and only 49+ will return collision? And only once but I want it to continue detecting still after it's detected one

Comment: The car's length might be 40, but I don't see that incorporated in the collision logic anywhere.  It looks like the positions need to be exactly equal within .1 of whatever unit of length this is.

Comment: Evan has a good point. Are you compensating for the length anywhere?

Comment: @StalemateOfTuning I changed the MIN_DIS to 40 to match the length of the car, it'll only print collision if the MIN_DIS is 49 or higher, but a collision won't be happening

Answer (score 1):

You may want to change the detection 'range'. If you look at the way you're detecting your cars, you're only looking for the co-ordinate that the sprite/vector is positioned at which is going to be relatively hard for them to collide if there are more than a few pixels. Try finding the position of `Car A` from the `width/length` of `Car B`.

Comment: I upped the detection range, my car length is 40 so i'd assume that would do it. All cars are the same length, but it will only return collision at 49+, but even when there are no collisions

Comment: I would highly recommend centring your vectors then getting that position like you did (`car.getPosition()`) and with that position as a variable, you can find the height range (`position +/- car.height`) and the width range (`position +/- (car.width/2)`)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the equality method is not correct. And it causes some collision detection problems.
We can not assume that two Car with the same property are the same object.
For example:

```
e.add(new Car(  0, 63, 2, new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0)));
e.add(new Car(  0, 63, 2, new Color(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f, 1.0)));
```

In this case there is a collision but it would never be detected since the two objects, through the equals method implemented, are the same.

In contexts like this, game engine or modelling system, it is useful to differentiate each object in your world with an ID, as each instance is unique.

Moreover as @Jason say, to correctly capture a collision you have to compute the length or the width of the object.

Comment: I've added the equals method

Comment: If you have two Car on your environment with the same (position,lane,speed,color) I suppose that you can't consider this car as the same. This can be a reason for some problem of collision detection. As @Jordan say you have to consider for collision the entire area occupied by the Cars